# Is there a way to stream output in Fastapi from the response I get from llama-index

Tags: python, langchain, llama-index

I have the following code where I am asking questions based on my context, and am able to get the respective outputs in streaming format. However,  I am creating an api for the same and not able to replicate similar results

```
from langchain import OpenAI
from types import FunctionType
from llama_index import ServiceContext, GPTVectorStoreIndex, LLMPredictor, PromptHelper, SimpleDirectoryReader, load_index_from_storage
import sys
import os
import time 
from llama_index.response.schema import StreamingResponse
import uvicorn 
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from pydantic import BaseModel
import uvicorn 



os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = "your key here" # gpt 3.5 turbo


app = FastAPI()

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=['*'],
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

from llama_index import StorageContext, load_index_from_storage, ServiceContext
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI

def construct_index(directory_path):
    max_input_size = 4096
    num_outputs = 5000
    max_chunk_overlap = 256
    chunk_size_limit = 3900
    file_metadata = lambda x : {"filename": x}
    reader = SimpleDirectoryReader(directory_path, file_metadata=file_metadata)
    
    documents = reader.load_data()

    prompt_helper = PromptHelper(max_input_size, num_outputs, max_chunk_overlap, chunk_size_limit=chunk_size_limit)
    llm_predictor = LLMPredictor(llm=OpenAI(temperature=0, model_name="gpt-3.5-turbo", max_tokens=num_outputs))
    
    service_context = ServiceContext.from_defaults(llm_predictor=llm_predictor, prompt_helper=prompt_helper)

    index = GPTVectorStoreIndex.from_documents(
        documents=documents, service_context = service_context
    )
    
    index.storage_context.persist("./jsons/contentstack_llm")
    return index
   
def get_index():
    max_input_size = 4000
    num_outputs = 1024
    max_chunk_overlap = 512
    chunk_size_limit = 3900
    prompt_helper = PromptHelper(max_input_size, num_outputs, max_chunk_overlap, chunk_size_limit=chunk_size_limit)
    llm_predictor = LLMPredictor(llm=ChatOpenAI(temperature=0, model_name="gpt-3.5-turbo", max_tokens=num_outputs, streaming = True))
    
    service_context = ServiceContext.from_defaults(llm_predictor=llm_predictor, prompt_helper=prompt_helper)
    
    return service_context  

# construct_index("./docs")
storage_context = StorageContext.from_defaults(persist_dir="./jsons/contentstack_llm")
service_context = get_index()
index = load_index_from_storage(storage_context, service_context = service_context)

query_engine = index.as_query_engine(streaming = True)
class Item(BaseModel):
    input_text: str

@app.post("/question_answering")
async def create_item(item: Item):
    input_sentence = item.input_text
    response = query_engine.query(input_sentence)
    links = []
    return StreamingResponse(query_engine.query(input_sentence).response_gen)
```

Upon executing the following code, `TypeError: cannot pickle 'generator' object`, I received the following error. Is there any workaround to do it in fastapi ? I am able to stream the answers in my console, but I would like to create a stream between my api and the output. Also, if not FastAPI, can we do a similar thing in Flask ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a quick fix, I did a quick hack using yield function of python and tagged it along with `StreamingResponse` of FastAPI, changed my code as follows

```
# from gpt_index import SimpleDirectoryReader, GPTListIndex,readers, GPTSimpleVectorIndex, LLMPredictor, PromptHelper
from langchain import OpenAI
import asyncio 
from types import FunctionType
from llama_index import ServiceContext, GPTVectorStoreIndex, LLMPredictor, PromptHelper, SimpleDirectoryReader, load_index_from_storage
import sys
import os
import time 
# from llama_index.response.schema import StreamingResponse
from fastapi.responses import StreamingResponse
import uvicorn 
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, WebSocket, WebSocketDisconnect
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from pydantic import BaseModel
import uvicorn 



os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = "your key here" # gpt 3.5 turbo


app = FastAPI()

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=['*'],
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

from llama_index import StorageContext, load_index_from_storage, ServiceContext
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI


def construct_index(directory_path):
    max_input_size = 4096
    num_outputs = 5000
    max_chunk_overlap = 256
    chunk_size_limit = 3900

    print("*"*5, "Documents parsing initiated", "*"*5)
    file_metadata = lambda x : {"filename": x}
    reader = SimpleDirectoryReader(directory_path, file_metadata=file_metadata)
    print(reader)
    documents = reader.load_data()
    print("*"*5, "Documents parsing done", "*"*5)
    
    print(documents[0].extra_info)
    print(documents[0].doc_id)
    
    print()
    # nodes = parser.get_nodes_from_documents(documents)
    # index = GPTVectorStoreIndex(nodes)
    prompt_helper = PromptHelper(max_input_size, num_outputs, max_chunk_overlap, chunk_size_limit=chunk_size_limit)
    llm_predictor = LLMPredictor(llm=OpenAI(temperature=0, model_name="gpt-3.5-turbo", max_tokens=num_outputs))
    
    service_context = ServiceContext.from_defaults(llm_predictor=llm_predictor, prompt_helper=prompt_helper)

    # print("*"*5, "Index creation initiated", "*"*5)
    index = GPTVectorStoreIndex.from_documents(
        documents=documents, service_context = service_context
    )
    # print("*"*5, "Index created", "*"*5)
    index.storage_context.persist("./jsons/contentstack_llm")
    return index
    


def get_index():
    max_input_size = 4000
    num_outputs = 1024
    max_chunk_overlap = 512
    chunk_size_limit = 3900
    prompt_helper = PromptHelper(max_input_size, num_outputs, max_chunk_overlap, chunk_size_limit=chunk_size_limit)
    llm_predictor = LLMPredictor(llm=ChatOpenAI(temperature=0, model_name="gpt-3.5-turbo", max_tokens=num_outputs, streaming = True))
    
    service_context = ServiceContext.from_defaults(llm_predictor=llm_predictor, prompt_helper=prompt_helper)
    
    return service_context  

# construct_index("./documents")
storage_context = StorageContext.from_defaults(persist_dir="./your_directory")
service_context = get_index()
index = load_index_from_storage(storage_context, service_context = service_context)

query_engine = index.as_query_engine(streaming = True)


async def astreamer(generator):
    try:
        for i in generator:
            yield (i)
            await asyncio.sleep(.1)
    except asyncio.CancelledError as e:
        
        print('cancelled')

class Item(BaseModel):
    input_text: str

@app.post("/question_answering")
async def create_item(item: Item):
    input_sentence = item.input_text
    response = query_engine.query(input_sentence)    
    return StreamingResponse(astreamer(response.response_gen), media_type="text/event-stream")
        

@app.get("/")
@app.get("/health_check")
async def health_check():
    return "ok"
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

Comment: Thank you for providing an answer to your own question! For the benefit of future users that may find this via searches, could you add clarity on whether this solution worked? The phrasing of "I tried" leaves it slightly ambiguous.

Comment: yes it did, and thanks for highlighting it out. I will update the solution

Comment: Can you please check my question, I am facing similar issues

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76357732/stream-a-langchain-openai-response-with-fastapi

Comment: Hello, can I ask why did you use sleep on astreamer?

Comment: @M.Erkin to not pull empty results from the streaming responses. new word is generated at every 0.1 secs. Roughly.